# submit handler for each input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to add a serialize event for an input in a form? Let's say I have a simple form.

```
<form action="blabla">
    <input type="text" name="first">
    <input type="text" name="second">
</form>
```

I want:

- the first input value to be retrieved as it is
- the second input value to be the base64-encoded-image-resized-through-canvas of the url specified within the input.

I'd like to attach a "serialize" event on the second input, so the when calling `$("form").serialize()` or `$("input[name=second]").val()` the value returned is not the one displayed, but a value returned by my handler.

Is there any way to achieve this? To trigger an handler when accessing an input value?

Comment: Why not just validate the field as lowercase, `<input type="text" name="second" pattern="[a-z]">`

Comment: That sort of data munging is best achieved on the server.

Comment: So you want to keep the possible uppercase characters the user has typed in the textbox and not make a simple javascript to convert them to lowercase as they are entered?

Comment: Nope, it was just the stupidest example for a callback. I'll edit the question